# BC30201 Expression expected. facing this issue

Tags: reporting-services

### `Dim modules As String() = NHWA Indicator MODULE. Split("|") Dim colors As String = ""` 
------issue for this line
There is an error on line 3 of custom code: [BC30201] Expression expected.

### The definition of the report '' is invalid.

An error occurred during local report processing. How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Please EDIT your question and use the code formatting tools in the toolbar to clean up the code in your question, as it is now it's difficult to make sense of. Also  read this which will help you ask a question that is more likely to be answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask